# How to uninstall Easyphp Devserver 16.1?

Tags: easyphp

There is no uninstall file in the folder! I could not find any way to uninstall Easyphp Devserver 16.1. I have to uninstall it, and then install again another version of the same software.

Answer (score 15):

There is no special entries anywhere in system. Simply delete EasyPHP 16.1 directory from Program Files *C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1*, and delete shortcode from desktop. That's all.

*Don't forget to backup or move databases that you might have created first!*

Comment: It didn't make any registry changes?

Comment: No, nothing in Registry. EasyPHP behave similar to portable app.

Answer (score 6):

I had found some useful information form EasyPHP Devserver websites.

It show that:
*You just have to delete the folder and the shortcut on your desktop. Nothing more.*

http://www.easyphp.org/support.php